Canvas completely broken now after dragging animation controller into scene?
I was trying to add some models and animations to the enemies in my level, but as soon as I dragged the model into the scene, and the animation controller into that, my canvas completely broke. Nothing shows up, including my buttons, background and text, and the whole canvas is completely invisible in the inspector as well. This is what it looks like for me:
Screenshot of Unity
Additionally, I get a whole bunch of errors I don't understand. Before I set the Project Settings < Player < Active Input Handling to both, I was getting an error message saying that I had an "Invalid AABB aabb", and I have no idea what that means.
Edit: I reloaded again, and managed to get the other error. Error 2
I just want my canvas back. What the Hell do I do?
I was expecting to just have the animation controller in the model object I dragged into the scene, and my canvas turned invisible and gave me several errors.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
